# DRY controllers in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Should I use DRY principles in controllers or code in different controllers can be repeated?
For example, now I have something like this:

```
class FirstController extends Controller
{
  public function store(FirstRequest $request)
  {
    $result = First::create($request->validated());
    
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully created'], 200);
   }
}
    
class SecondController extends Controller
{
  public function store(SecondRequest $request)
  {
    $result = Second::create($request->validated());
    
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully created'], 200);
  }
}

...

class NController extends Controller
{
  public function store(NRequest $request)
  {
    $result = N::create($request->validated());
    
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully created'], 200);
  }
}
```

How can I make them DRY?

Should I use main controller class which would be extended by FirsrController, SecondController etc? Something like this:

```
class MainController extends Controller
{
  protected $model;
  public function store($request)
  {
    $result = $this->model::create($request->validated());
                    
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully created'], 200);
   }
}
            
class FirstController extends MainController
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->model = new First();
  }
}
            
class SecondController extends MainController
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->model = new Second();
  }
}
```

And how can I use different request for them in that case?

Comment: If you're looking at DRY also take a look at [WET and AHA](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/dry-wet-or-aha-7c2132aaf047). I really suggest you avoid premature optimizations.

Comment: Personally, I disagree with your method to make the code more DRY, I think it is just making it more complicated. I suggest replacing `response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully created'], 200)` with a new response class(`CreatedResponse`) which can inherit from laravel `JsonResponse` and sets status code and message in the constructor instead of cluttering the controller. BTW, maybe consider 201 for created instead of 200

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like `return YourCustomResponse::success();` in both controllers, where `success()` will be a named constructor.

Comment: Thank you, but i need something else, like MainController class which would be extended by another controllers

Comment: Sure, but take in account degree of coupling you will get by inheritance. Maybe it it will costs more than not so DRY controllers.

Comment: Сan you suggest how can I use different Requests in that case?

Comment: Do you mean how to customize response for different cases?  You can pass parameters to `success` or use another named constructor (`fail()` for example).

Comment: Not this. In example above I have function store($request) in MainController, FirstController and SecondController extend MainController, but FirstController has FirstRequest and SecondController has SecondRequest validation classes. If I overwrite function store in each controller: public function store(FirstRequest $request) and public function store(SecondRequest $request) I will get error that declaration should be compatible. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Ok, I understand, you mean case of inheritance. It's actually demonstrate unwanted coupling I mentioned. No good way to deal with it. In my opinion, in most cases inheritance is not good way to eliminate code duplication. Different forms of composition (like one I initially suggest) gives much more supple design.

Comment: Can you recommend a CRUD API example on githab or elsewhere? I would be grateful

Answer (score 0):

First define two interfaces (contracts) like so:

```
interface ActionContract{
    public function store();
}

interface RequestContract
{
    public function rules();
}
```

Provide the implementations like so:

```
class MainRequest{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

class FirstRequest extends MainRequest implements RequestContract
{

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
          'email'    => 'required',
          'password' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}

class FirstAction implements ActionContract{

    public function store()
    {

    }
}
// SecondAction implements ActionContract
// ThirdAction implements ActionContract
```

Instead of using multiple controllers use one central controller in which you will be injecting the interfaces NOT concrete implementations:

```
class CentralController extends Controller
{
    public function store(ActionContract $action, RequestContract $request)
    {
        $action->store($request->validated());
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully created'], 200);
    }
}
```

Define a service provider which will be responsible to provide the correct implementation; example:

```
class MyProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
// define a lookup table in a service provider
// and resolve corresponding Model and Request
// depending upon the request
protected array $actionImplementations
                  = [
  '/first' =>
    [
      'model'        => Firsrt::class,
      'formRequest' => FirstRequest::class,
    ],

  '/second' =>
    [
      'model'        => Second::class,
      'formRequest' => SecondRequest::class,
    ],
];

public function register()
{
    app()->singleton(ActionContract::class, function ($app) {
        $class = $this->getAuthImplementation()['model'];
        return new $class;
    });

    app()->singleton(RequestContract::class, function ($app) {
        $class = $this->getAuthImplementation()['formRequest'];
        return new $class;
    });

}

public function getAuthImplementation(): array
{
    return $this->authImplementations[$this->requestedUrl()];
}


protected function requestedUrl(): string
{
    return parse_url(request()->url(), PHP_URL_PATH);
}
```

Now your controller isn't worried about which model it is dealing with; and when you want to create a brand new NthController make it regular class and implement from ActionContract and make an entry in service provider so that it can resolve the correct implementation.